# Trello - How to bulk delete all the cards older than 12 months

Tags: trello

My trello board is extremely slow. Has thousands of cards with images in them. I need the images too so cannot 'view without images'. How do I delete all the cards older than 12 months? Atleast archive?

I tried searching for a solution and there's no solution at all to try on the entire INTERNET

Comment: Well, what have you tried so far?

Comment: I tried searching for a solution and there's no solution at all to try